# navigation button images disappear on mobile when hit back button in browser

Tags: html, ios, css

I'm an amateur web designer with HTML experience mostly.  I'm building my own website for a hobby, and ran into this snag.  I've only recently noticed it though, so I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the recent iOS update?

Like the title says, when I go to my website, everything is fine.  Then I click on one of the links to the "Contact" page, let's say (or any of the links that take you to another page), and then hit the browser's back button to go back to the previous page, the button's image I had just clicked on ("Contact" button) has disappeared and I'm just left with the button's name I named it.  This repeats for every button I click and then hit back in the browser.  This only happens on mobile devices though (I've only had the opportunity to check on an Apple phone and iPad).  It doesn't happen on my laptop.  I've tried searching for answers to this, but can't find any.  I've only just noticed this happening though, which leads me to believe it might be a software update issue? Although it's entirely possible I just never noticed before.

Here is my website so that anyone interested in helping can take a look and let me know what you think might be the problem/solution.  Thank you very much for any help you may be able to provide.

https://www.atomicorchard.com/

Comment: Hey, welcome to stack overflow. In the future, it would be nice for you to be able to show some code of at least what you think the problem could be. In this case, it seems to be a CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's okay on my end. Try optimizing your images and check your JavaScript. The problem may be occurred once that script is being executed. And try adding media queries.

Comment: Here is the typical code I use for the links:  

<a href="http://www.atomicorchard.com/contact.html" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore()" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('Contactbutton','','images/Contact_6_over.jpg',1)"><img src="/images/Contact_6.jpg" alt="Contactbutton" width="100" height="50" id="Contactbutton" /></a>